# direct use of MySQL fetch_assoc through $row in while($row) loop cause system hang

Tags: php, mysqli

I have written a code like this and this cause my system hang.
I don't know how this happen...

```
<?php 
    $connect = new MySQL('localhost','root','','database');

    $query = "select * from table";
    $result =$connect->query ($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    while($row){
        echo $row['id'];
    }
?>
```

List item

This script cause my system fully hanged

Comment: `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){`

Comment: This code work but why do my code causes system hang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you fetch one row with `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();` and then iterate in the `while` loop until this changes. But as you never change the value of `$row`, the loop runs forever.

This could work:

`while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {`

Comment: Yes this work perfectly but I want to know why my code causes such system hang

Comment: If you code does not finish execution, it runs and runs and runs and runs.... and runs - thats exactly why your system hangs

Comment: @Rajesh - This answer does explain just that; you've created an infinite loop. _"But as you never change the value of $row, the loop runs forever."_ == system hang.

Comment: @Rajesh If this answer solved your issue you, you should accept it.

Comment: I need one more help...how to append json value in inside div tag using JavaScript